# Why i get results of this ajax call instantly though I have async code?

Tags: python, django, python-3.9

I am studying async programming with Python and I cannot get why I get instant answer when I call route corresponding to this call (I call it as ajax call, platform is Django, this file is **views.py** file in Django app)?

(When I click on button ajax calls buy method, it simulates buying some stock with sandbox and returns result, I want it to wait 5 secs and then return result, instead I get results of ajax call nearly immediately)

```
async def buy(request):

    figi = request.GET.get('figi', 'missing')
    data = {
        'result': 'success',
        'figi': figi
    }

    SANDBOX_TOKEN = 'some_token'

    async def buy_stock():
        try:
            async with TinkoffInvestmentsRESTClient(
                token=SANDBOX_TOKEN) as rest:
    
                order = await rest.orders.create_market_order(
                    figi="BBG000BTR593",
                    lots=1,
                    operation=OperationType.BUY,
                )
    
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
    
                result = await rest.orders.create_limit_order(
                    figi="BBG000BTR593",
                    lots=1,
                    operation=OperationType.SELL,
                    price=50.3,
                )
    
                return 'result'
        except TinkoffInvestmentsError as e:
            print(e)
    
    result = await buy_stock()    
    
    return JsonResponse({
        'result': 'success',
        'message': result
    }, safe=False)
```

In other words, seems call doesn't wait for async methods to finish and immediately sends JsonResponse

Comment: Is the print in the except triggered? Was `message == 'result'`?

Comment: No, I get answer with message == null. So it doesn't wait for awaitables and instantly returns JsonResponse. The documentation is really scarce on this topic

Comment: Maybe it's ok cause JsonResponse is not async. But question is how I can really return json after all async work is done

Comment: It is probably null because there was an exception, so it went to: `except TinkoffInvestmentsError as e:`, which will cause the function to return None